# How can I link a framework at a custom path to my executable?

Tags: cmake

I have the following:

```
add_executable(app src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(app "-framework ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/macOS/aRandomFramework.framework")
```

However, I am getting `ld: framework not found path/to/lib/macOS/aRandomFramework.framework` but I do see the framework there in the path.

Not sure what I could be missing here.. any help is appreciated!

P.S. aRandomFramework is a framework that is located under the tree of my project and it's not located in the default search path of the system.

UPDATE: Added `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`

directory layout:

```
app
|-deps
|-lib
  |-macOS
    |-aRandomFramework.framework
|-CMakeLists.txt
|-src
  |-main.cpp
```

Comment: Do NOT use **relative** paths in `target_link_libraries`: It is unspecified with which current directory the linker will be called. Use **absolute** paths instead. You could use `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` which refers to the directory with `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: I suspect that the linker fails to resolve the relative path to the framework since it is not executed with your project root as the working directory. You can try `target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE "-framework ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/macOS/aRandomFramework.framework")` instead.

Comment: I changed it to `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/macOS/aRandomFramework.framework` and I still get framework not found

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could describe the directory layout in more detail. In particular, where is the CMakeLists.txt located relative to the framework you're searching. I suspect `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` doesn't work because the excerpt you've shown is in a `CMakeLists.txt` in a `src` subdirectory and not the project root. But I can't be sure without knowing your project layout.

Comment: @corristo, tsyvarev, I just added the directory layout

Comment: @tsyvarev any ideas?

Comment: Hm, actually `-framework` part is not needed when use absolute path: `target_link_libraries(app ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/macOS/aRandomFramework.framework")`. CMake should be able to automatically transform that into combination of `-framework` and `-F` options. See e.g. description of [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html) about a framework.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you cannot directly reference a framework's path.
I was able to get around it by using the find_library pointing to the local resource and then using the variable created with that method as reference to it:

```
add_executable(app src/main.cpp)
find_library(fmkReference
    NAMES aRandomFramework
    PATHS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/macOS
    REQUIRED NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
target_link_libraries(app ${fmkReference})
```